# Why do I get "406 Not Acceptable" for this request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get a JSON response in my browser but I'm getting:

> Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

It should work. I have the following code in my controller:

```
respond_to :json
  def get_current_value
  stocks = Stockexchange.find(:all)

  respond_with(stocks) do |format|
   format.json { render :json => stocks.to_json}
  end
 return
end
```

Comment: Are you setting the `Accept` header to `application/json` when making the request? Have you tested it using a generic HTTP client to verify it's a server-side problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to force Rails into using the JSON format in its response is to add `.json` to the URL you're requesting. Once you get that working, you can try playing with the headers and such.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def get_current_value
  @stocks = Stockexchange.find(:all)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  # Presumes existence of get_current_value.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @stocks }
  end
end
```

Get rid of the format.html if you only ever want it to return json.